# C++20 lambdas with non type template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

I'm messing around with new C++20 lambdas, it seems I can declare a lambda taking a non type template param, but then I'm not able to call it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    // compiles fine
    auto f = []<bool ok>() { return ok; };

    // it even has an address??
    std::cout << &f;

    // f();    // error : no matching function for call to object of typ
    // f<true>(); // error : invalid operands to binary expression

    f.operator()<true>(); // compiles but somewhat... ugly
}
```

I looked at the relevant paper [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0428r2.pdf) but it doesn't seem to mention the calling syntax in such a case.

Is explicitly passing template arguments at the lambda call site forbidden? It would be a disappointing limitation, as I thought the intention was to make lambdas able to do as much as templates.

Comment: One possibility would be to call the function template inside the lambda directly: `f.operator()<true>();`. Not sure whether there is another way.

Comment: @tkausl, Nice, this didn't come to my mind by it works :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is explicitly passing template arguments at the lambda call site forbidden?

No, but the issue is you're not specifying the template argument for the right entity. Note that `f` itself is not a template. It's an object of a non-templated type that *contains* a member `operator()` that is templated.

So when you do:

```
f<true>(); // error
```

you are specifying the template argument for `f`, but since `f` is not a template, you get an error.

On the other hand, as you've observed, this call:

```
f.operator()<true>();  // ok
```

is fine, because you are specifying the template argument for `f`'s `operator()` which is indeed a template.

Also, this issue has nothing to do with non-type template parameters for lambdas, the same thing would happen if it were a type template parameter as well.

Comment: If the lambda itself, i.e., the function object, cannot be parameterized, I wonder whether `f<true>()` could have been defined by the standard as a kind of syntactic sugar for `f.operator()<true>()`.

Comment: @plexando I can't see any reason that wouldn't work. However, it would be an additional rule for not much benefit I think.

Comment: @plexando: `f<true>(1)` already means `(f<true)>1` when `f` is a value (not a template).

Comment: @DavisHerring Well, that's that :) I didn't even think of that :)

Comment: @Davis Herring: :) Yeah right, Mr. (Red) Herring. And I always wondered who's behind this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c).

Comment: I wonder if it would be plausible to parse out `value< template arguments >()` and automatically convert to `value.operator()< template arguments >()`.  It could be parsing hell.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It's an interesting question. I can't think of a scenario where `value< args >()` could reasonably mean something else, but if it could, parsing unambiguously won't be possible :(

Comment: @cigien I'd be more worried about `value less than some complex expression greater than` prefix being parsed, then discarded when you hit `()`.  Making the C++ parser even more complex would suck.